# VirtualHost: не работают поддомены

Tags: php, hosts, virtual

Проблема в том, что домен открывается, а при открытии поддомена, выскакивает ошибка, что сайта такого нету.

Система - Centos 6.4 x64

```
<VirtualHost *:80>    ServerName site.ru    ServerAlias www.site.ru    DocumentRoot /hdd/backup/www/dd/site    ErrorLog /hdd/backup/www/logs/error-site.ru.log<Directory /hdd/backup/www/dd/site>    Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI    AllowOverride AuthConfig FileInfo    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html    Order allow,deny    Allow from all</Directory><Directory /hdd/backup/www/dd/site>    AllowOverride None    Options None    Order allow,deny    Allow from all</Directory></VirtualHost><VirtualHost *:80>    ServerName forum.site.ru    ServerAlias www.forum.site.ru    DocumentRoot /hdd/backup/www/dd/forum    ErrorLog /hdd/backup/www/logs/error-forum.site.ru.log<Directory /hdd/backup/www/dd/forum>    Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI    AllowOverride AuthConfig FileInfo    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html    Order allow,deny    Allow from all</Directory><Directory "/hdd/backup/www/forum.site.ru">    AllowOverride None    Options None    Order allow,deny    Allow from all</Directory></VirtualHost><VirtualHost *:80>    ServerName wiki.site.ru    ServerAlias www.wiki.site.ru    DocumentRoot /hdd/backup/www/dd/wiki    ErrorLog /hdd/backup/www/logs/error-wiki.site.ru.log<Directory /hdd/backup/www/dd/wiki>    Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI    AllowOverride AuthConfig FileInfo    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html    Order allow,deny    Allow from all</Directory><Directory /hdd/backup/www/dd/wiki>    AllowOverride None    Options None    Order allow,deny    Allow from all</Directory></VirtualHost>
```

**nslookup**

```
C:\Users\Nicolayka>nslookup 8.8.8.8 www.site.ru*** Не найден адрес сервера для "www.site.ru":╤хЁтхЁ:  UnKnownAddress:  192.168.1.1╚ь :     google-public-dns-a.google.comAddress:  8.8.8.8
```

Comment: SELinux я отключил

Comment: какая ошибка, ошибка от веб-сервера или, что скорее всего, от днс?! Если от веб сервера, то какая?

Comment: Ну обычная, когда сайта не существует как будто

Comment: ну так пинганите поддомен по имени, более чем уверен что он не разрезолвит имя.

Comment: http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У кого домен покупали, посмотрите у них в панели настройки для DNS. Возможно там нет записи для поддоменов.

Comment: С этим проблему решил. Проблема переросла в --> http://admin.hashcode.ru/questions/7455/php-virtualhost-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8B-%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD